# Where is the cache for SDWebImage?

Tags: ios, caching, sdwebimage

I checked the NSBundle but couldn't find the cache where the images are saved by SDWebImage. Is the cache even enabled (see code below)? According to the [Docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/SDWebImage/3.7.5/) it does the caching management.

As given in docs:

> Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the
>   sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method from the
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDataSource method.
>   **Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching
>   management**.

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

...

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Here we use the new provided sd_setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
        [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sandbox's Library folder

Your Application ID/Library/Caches/com.hackemist.SDWebImageCache.default/

Answer (score 1):

Search below line of code in your project. `_diskCachePath` is the `cache` of `SDWebImage`.

```
if (![_fileManager fileExistsAtPath:_diskCachePath]) {
                [_fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:_diskCachePath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL];
            }
```